# Rails RESTful API: the proper error format when content negotiation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

What error format must be used by RESTful API when content negotiation fails (`ActionController::UnknownFormat` is raised):

- when a controller responds to the only one format (e. g. JSON) and the user has requested another one (e. g. XML), should the error be generated as JSON object or XML one?
- when a controller responds to several formats and the user has requested neither of them, which one should be used during error generation: one of the 'known' by the controller or the one, having been requested by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are under no obligation to respond to any invalid request with the same format as the request was made. Imagine getting a request with payload in unknown binary format - what are you supposed to do in such a case.

`ActionController::UnknownFormat` [should](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23062) trigger a `406 Not Acceptable` response, probably will in Rails 5.

You should rescue the `ActionController::UnknownFormat` and respond with proper HTTP code as well as set an `Accept` header listing all formats that your API supports (if Rails doesn't do it by default, I'm not sure)

Comment: Rails 4.1.1 by default responds to `ActionController::UnknownFormat`: - with xml/yaml object, if `application/xml` or `application/yaml` was requested; - otherwise it responds with empty html page with a header `Content-Type: text/html`